# Cannot read property '0' of null error while adding a lightning component in lightning app builder canvas

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a report and corresponding to it I have created a lightning component to display it on Home page.
But as soon as I am adding this lightning component in lightning app builder canvas it is popping up an error message as 'Cannot read property '0' of null'.
I think if the added component is saved with null values in right side, then this error appears. But why it is appearing as soon as adding to canvas.

Comment: Please share your component code so we can see what is happening